# Haproxy - How to parse and store parts of an incoming URL

Tags: parsing, url, haproxy

If I have an incoming url like so:

foo.com/FooID/1234/FooLocation/NYC

How do I go about extracting these values from the incoming request so I can use them for a lookup in a map file. I know this must be doable with regex, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution similar to extracting url parameters:

Example:

`http-request set-header X-FooId %[url_param(FooID)].`

If not, which regex function would be best used in this instance so I could either store this value or access it directly via a header?